Log4Cxx Blocks Calling Thread While Logging?
I'm using log4cxx::rolling::RollingFileAppender() for logging in my C++ application, without any asynchronous appenders. If I invoke logging from the main thread, will the main thread be blocked until the log string is written to the log file? Moreover, How should I demonstrate this behavior?
If I incorporate asynchronous appenders, would it potentially disrupt the logging order or introduce unexpected delays in a multithreaded scenario? I'm particularly concerned about the impact on logging consistency and performance. Can someone offer insights into how asynchronous logging behaves under these circumstances?
I have experienced a critical thread delay on one of the message receiving thread, logger logged the expected log line after 1 second delay as follows.
2024-04-03 22:55:14,221 [0x00001290]     INFO   <..>
2024-04-03 22:55:14,221 [0x00001290]     INFO   <..>
2024-04-03 22:55:14,221 [0x00001290]    DEBUG   <..>
2024-04-03 22:55:14,221 [0x00001290]     INFO   <..>
2024-04-03 22:55:14,221 [0x00001290]     INFO   <..>
2024-04-03 22:55:14,221 [0x00001290]     INFO   <..>
2024-04-03 22:55:15,237 [0x00004a44]    DEBUG   <..>
2024-04-03 22:55:14,237 [0x00003c5c]     INFO   <..>
2024-04-03 22:55:15,237 [0x00000450]    DEBUG   <..>
2024-04-03 22:55:16,018 [0x00001290]     INFO   <..>
2024-04-03 22:55:16,018 [0x00000450]    DEBUG   <..>
2024-04-03 22:55:16,018 [0x00003c5c]     INFO   <..>

Here log line "2024-04-03 22:55:14,237  [0x00003c5c]" is logged after "2024-04-03 22:55:15,237  [0x00004a44]" also the timestamp is getting fetched by log4cxx only, so here based on other message processing delays I'm suspecting logger got stuck and blocked the calling thread.

From a quick look at the implementation of asyncappender it looks like it uses a simple ringbuffer. Messages from the same thread will appear in order; different threads should be semi-ordered, depending on who gets the lock. As long as the writer can keep up, printing a log message should be very cheap. (much cheaper than writing to a file)

Anything that isn't asynchronous will block the calling thread.

@Botje I think asyncAppender should solve this issue.

@user207421 But is there anyway to demonstrate  log4cxx blocking the main thread, like anyways to simulate slow logging. Because this incident is critical but,  not able to reproduce

@Friedrich I will update this, Thanks

@Botje Can you suggest a way to demonstrate  "calling thread waiting for logging to complete", I have tried few but log4cxx is very adaptable, couldn't simulate any delay .

Use a LD_PRELOAD hack to introduce arbitrary delays in file operations?

@Botje We are having windows environment, LD_PRELOAD is wont work I guess. But I was able put delay in the write function in fileoutputsteam class of log4cxx and this modified log4cxx library is found useful for file write delay demonstration.

@Botje But I have observed something strange with the AsyncAppender, It is not blocking the calling thread initially due to the file write delay, but later it fills up the buffer and blocks the calling thread, on setting a large buffer for AsyncAppender everything is found going fine

That's not strange at all. That is a consequence of your log producer waiting for a free slot in the ring buffer because the writer is busy writing files instead of taking messages from the ring.

Log4cxx performance has been improved by the last 2 releases, Release 1.3.0 significantly reduced the overhead of sending events to the appender and release 1.2.0 reduced the frequency of mutex contention when sending envents to the appender.
Log4cxx can not guarantee entries in the log file are in the order in which logging requests are generated. The timestamp indicates the time the request was generated (i.e. when the LOG4CXX_INFO macro was executed). The operating system scheduler may suspend a thread between LoggingEvent creation and the system call that adds to the log file.
AsyncAppender has been extensively overhaulled in release 1.3.0 to improve thoughput when logging from multiple threads (see the times in example benchmarks)
